# Is point a square?

Tags: geometry

I was solving a problem where there are 4 points and we need to check if they form a square or not. Now if all 4 points are the same, is it square or not. My initial thought was it is a zero-sided square but wanted to clarify if my understanding is right or not.

Comment: I'd say no. A square is a polygon, and according to http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Polygon.html a polygon can't have three or more collinear points.

Comment: If anyone considers a point to be a square, it would be a very degenerate square because it would also be a disk. Though there is a homotopy equivalence between a solid square and a point, it is not relevant to the problem you are solving.

Comment: This depends heavily on context; it's a square if it would be convenient for it to be a square in the context you're working. (Sometimes, it's also convenient to sort of dodge the issue and call it a degenerate square)

Comment: The answer is no. A square has side length $\ell>0$. A point clearly does not satisfy this property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A point say (h,k) is a point circle:of zero radius.
$$(x-h)^2+(y-k)^2=0$$ or also a point-square  $$|x-h|+|y-k|=0.$$

Comment: But a circle can never be a square right?

Comment: Do you mean $(x−h)^2+(y−k)^2=0$?

Comment: Yes, corrected it now.

Comment: This is a heavily topological answer and I am not sure if it helps him. It sounds to me like he is doing a coding exercise.

Answer (score 0):

If $a \le b$ and $c \le d$ then we have two cases:

1. $a < b$ and $c< d$, then $[a,b] \times [c,d]$ is a rectangle (in $ \mathbb R^2$).
2. $a= b$ or $c = d$, then $[a,b] \times [c,d]$ is a degenerate rectangle (in $ \mathbb R^2$).

Comment: Not a square unless $b-a=d-c$.